# How to find the numver of duplicate lines, each line contains a few numbers seperated by spaces

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

Suppose i have a file like this...

```
4  2  8  2 12  3 18  2 22  2 26  2 28  3 30  2      
4  3 10  2 14  2 18  2 20  3 22  2 28  2 32  2      
2  3 10  3 12  2 16  2 18  3 20  2 24  2 26  3     
1  3  3  3 17  3 19  3 26  2 28  2 30  2 32  2 
4  2  8  2 12  3 18  2 22  2 26  2 28  3 30  2
```

the first and the last line are the same in the input...

I want the output to be like ...

```
4  2  8  2 12  3 18  2 22  2 26  2 28  3 30  2  2     
4  3 10  2 14  2 18  2 20  3 22  2 28  2 32  2  1   
2  3 10  3 12  2 16  2 18  3 20  2 24  2 26  3  1   
1  3  3  3 17  3 19  3 26  2 28  2 30  2 32  2  1
```

The extra last coloum in the output simply specifies the extra number of lines.....

how can i do this in bash...

i know the `sort` command but it only works with one number per line....

Comment: close: `sort | uniq -c`; it will result in `<count> line...` though and the input is sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from [sehe's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100675/how-to-find-the-numver-of-duplicate-lines-each-line-contains-a-few-numbers-sepe#comment22989520_16100675), what about this?

```
sort your_file | uniq -c | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf $i"\t"; printf $1"\n"}'
```

Output:

```
1       3       3       3       17      3       19      3       26      2       28      2       30      2       32      2       1
2       3       10      3       12      2       16      2       18      3       20      2       24      2       26      3       1
4       2       8       2       12      3       18      2       22      2       26      2       28      3       30      2       2
4       3       10      2       14      2       18      2       20      3       22      2       28      2       32      2       1
```

Comment: `printf "$1\n"` or `printf $1"\n"`?

Comment: You are completly right, @devnull. Just edited my answer. Thanks!